# Extract the n-th digit of a number in Sagemath

Tags: python, math, sage

How is it possible to extract the n-th digit of a number in Sagemath?  We have to compute the 13787th digit from `pi + e` in Sagemath. My approach was the following:

```
sage: xi = e + pi
....: var1 = xi.n(digits=13786+1)
....: var2 = xi.n(digits=13787+1)
....: var3 = ((var2-var1) * 10^13787).trunc()
....: var3
0
```

Which gave me `0` back, however it should be `9`.

Comment: You're assuming that `xi.n` will give you exactly the correct digits.  That's unlikely, for two reasons: (1) the approximation is more likely to round than truncate (for example, if computing `pi` to 4 places after the decimal point I'd expect to get `3.1416`, rather than the initial portion `3.1415...` of the sequence), and (2) there's likely to be some inaccuracy inherent in the approximation process. Indeed, the [docs](http://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/misc/sage/misc/functional.html#sage.misc.functional.numerical_approx) say "No guarantee is made about the accuracy of the result."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The digit is indeed 9. But the subsequent digits are also 9: this part of decimal expansion goes ...9999237... Rounding rolls these 9s to 0s, carrying 1 to a higher digit.

So you need some extra digits in order to avoid the digit you are interested in from being affected by rounding. How many depends on the number; we don't know in advance if there isn't a sequence of one billion of 9s starting from that position. Here I use 10 extra digits

```
xi = e + pi
n = 13787
offset = 1 + floor(log(xi, 10))   # the first significant figure is not always the first digit after decimal dot, so we account for that 
extra = 10
digit = int(str(xi.n(digits = n + offset + extra))[-1 - extra])
```

This returns 9. I think extracting with `str` is more reliable than subtracting two nearly-equal numbers and hoping there won't be additional loss of precition there.

Of course, including a magic number like 10 isn't reliable. Here is a better version, which starts with 10 extra digits but then increases the number until we no longer have 00000000... as a result.

```
xi = e + pi
n = 13787
offset = 1 + floor(log(xi, 10))
extra = 10
while True:
   digits = str(xi.n(digits = n + offset + extra))[-1 - extra:]
   if digits == "0" * len(digits):
       extra *= 2
   else:
       digit = int(digits[0])
       break
print(digit)
```

This will loop forever if the digits keep coming as 0, and *rightly so*: without actually knowing what the number is we can never be sure if the ...0000000... we get is not really ...999999999942... rounded up.